# Kindle NCX with Chapter Header images

Tags: scrivener, kindle, table-of-contents

For my book in Scrivener, I have custom images as each chapter heading instead of just "Chapter 1", which works well. However, that means the Scrivener generated Table of Contents doesn't work for me (Scrivener automatically replaces the text of the chapter link in the ToC with the image link, which doesn't show up in the ToC, so you just end up with a blank page for your Table of Contents), so instead I wrote the Table of Contents out myself and linked them to my folders, which works perfectly.

However, my custom Table of Contents isn't populating the NCX ToC in the Kindle app. How can I fix that?

I've tried checking and unchecking "Use flat list of contents in navigation controls (NCX)", but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured this out myself just now. Scrivener was replacing document links with my title prefix (i.e., my custom images for chapter headings), even in the NCX.

So I needed to uncheck "Update titles in document links with prefix and suffix settings" under "Title Adjustments".

Hopefully this saves someone else lots of time if they decide to use custom chapter headings and can't get their NCX to work.